# Regarding XML Parsing

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

I am using IXMLDOMNodeListPtr , IXMLDOMNodePtr , IXMLDOMElementPtr and IXMLDOMDocPtr.  I am having little confusion over here i.e. Should i have to call Release() on these pointers before they go out of scope.

Thanks.

Comment: what XML library are you using?

Comment: I have included 
#include <msxml2did.h>
#include <msxml2.h>

in my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no. These `XXXPtr` types are typdefs for instantations of the `_com_ptr_t` template class. This class is essentially a smart COM ptr wrapper class and deals with calls to `AddRef` and `Release` for you.